# how to number distinct values while respecting their original ordering?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, dense-rank

Here's my input data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test AS SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  (1, 12),
  (2, 7),
  (3, 8),
  (4, 8),
  (5, 7)
) AS rows (position, value);
```

I want to, in a single query (no subqueries or CTEs), assign a unique number for each distinct `value`.  However, I also want those numbers to ascend according to the associated `position` -- i.e., a distinct `value`'s number should be assigned according to its lowest `position`.

Assumptions:

- each row will always have a unique `position`
- `value` is not guaranteed unique per row
- the number of a distinct value is only for ordinal purposes, e.g. it doesn't matter whether `distinct_values` goes 1-2-3 or 3-8-14

The desired output is:

```
 position | value | distinct_value 
----------+-------+----------------
        1 |    12 |              1
        2 |     7 |              2
        3 |     8 |              3
        4 |     8 |              3
        5 |     7 |              2
```

I can get close using `DENSE_RANK` to number distinct values:

```
SELECT
  position,
  value,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS distinct_value
  FROM test ORDER BY position;
```

The result obviously ignores `position`:

```
 position | value | distinct_value 
----------+-------+----------------
        1 |    12 |              3
        2 |     7 |              1
        3 |     8 |              2
        4 |     8 |              2
        5 |     7 |              1
```

Is there a better window function for this?

Comment: IMO syntactically the simplest way is `select *, array_position((select array_agg(value order by position) from test), value) from test;` but it obviously is not efficient for large table.

Answer (score 2):

```
with 
  t(x,y) as (values
    (1, 12),
    (2, 7),
    (3, 8),
    (4, 8),
    (5, 7)),
  pos(i,y) as (select min(x), y from t group by y),
  ind(i,y) as (select row_number() over(order by i), y from pos)
select * from ind join t using(y) order by x;
```

Comment: this works and is essentially what I'm doing now, but it's on a huge dataset and the join is killing performance, hence the stipulation of a single query

Comment: @rcrogers Tested on 1000000 rows on my 8 years-old notebook. For y in 1-100 it is about 6 secs, and for y in 1-1000 it is about 8 secs. Not so fast but it is 1000000 rows... In any case I hope that somebody  will find more efficient solution.